# React Component Re-Renders when updating input using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on a React Project. I'm building a form with about 5 fields in it. I've used React Hooks to manage the state of the updates however when I enter in an input into the field. I can see the component re-render each time I enter a key stroke. the re-render is causing issues because it sets a state of a form field back to empty. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Link to a gif of the re-render on keystroke can be found here: https://gph.is/g/ZxDqzmN

Link to clearing the form field: https://gph.is/g/4LjmDpd

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";


import {
  Button,
  CardContent,
  Dialog,
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  DialogContentText,
  DialogTitle,
  Card as MuiCard,
  Paper as MuiPaper,
  TextField,
} from "@material-ui/core";

import { spacing } from "@material-ui/system";

export default function EmployeeFormDialog() {
  const [open, setDialog] = useState(null);
  const [carName, setCarName] = useState([""]);

  const onSubmit = (data, event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(data);
    setDialog(false);
  };

  console.log("re-render");

  const Card = styled(MuiCard)(spacing);

  const Paper = styled(MuiPaper)(spacing);

  return (
    <Card mb={6}>
      <CardContent>
        <Paper mt={4}>
          <div>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => setDialog(true)}>
              Add New Cars
            </Button>
            <Dialog open={open} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title" disableEnforceFocus="true">
              <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Add New Car</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                  <DialogContentText>To add new car</DialogContentText>
                  <TextField
                    onChange={(e) => setCarName(e.target.value)}
                    defaultValue={carName}
                    name="carName"
                    margin="dense"
                    id="carName"
                    label="Car Name"
                    type="text"
                    fullWidth
                  />
                  <TextField
                    autoFocus
                    name="carYear"
                    margin="dense"
                    id="carYear"
                    label="Car Year"
                    type="text"
                    fullWidth
                  />
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                  <Button type="button" onClick={() => setDialog(false)} color="primary">
                    Cancel
                  </Button>
                  <Button type="submit" color="primary">
                    Add Car
                  </Button>
                </DialogActions>
              </form>
            </Dialog>
          </div>
        </Paper>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Comment: One option to consider is extracting the form to a new component and adding a `onSubmit` prop that the parent component uses to close the dialog and make api calls. Also, you may be able to use react-hook-form but I’m not sure how well it works with Material UI.

Comment: That is because your component rerenders with every stroke to actually show the newly typed letter :) That is the expected result. Your gif is unavailable, can you provide more information on what is being cleared?

Comment: Thanks for looking into that. I've updated the gif link to work: https://gph.is/g/ZxDqzmN

Comment: The main issue is you're declaring `const Card` and `const Paper` inside the component function. This causes the entire component to completely re-render. Move the two lines outside your component function. Full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-jackson-h6c4p?file=/src/EmployeeFormDialog.js

Comment: Chris G I could hug you! Thanks mate. I regret not posting this 24 hours ago. Thanks for your help...

Comment: No problem :) Hooks can be tricky

Comment: The question looks like solved.... Could you answer your question, and check it as resolved, please?